# How to see the changes that were pulled on a `git pull`?

Tags: git

After (or before) doing a `git pull`, is there an easy way to see what the updates are that have been pushed by others to the branch I am working on?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/how-can-i-generate-a-git-diff-of-whats-changed-since-the-last-time-i-pulled help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd first do a

```
git fetch
```

to pull the new commits, but not merge them yet. Then you could log the changes between your current repository and the remote origin:

```
git log HEAD..origin
```

Finally, merge the changes:

```
git merge origin
```

---

For example:

```
$ git fetch

[...]
From github.com:blah
   00f82fa..38e4017  master     -> origin/master
```

and:

```
$ git log HEAD..origin
commit 38e4017bc89a6eb41252465cbde68f7d897377cb
Author: Werner Robitza
Date:   Tue Jul 12 10:56:49 2011 -0700

    Edited Gemfile via GitHub
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than pulling the other branch into yours, you can first inspect the commits that will be pulled in with `git log MINE..THEIRS`.  If it is a remote branch, you can fetch their latest changes for the comparison with `git remote update`.